# Share button not sharing the respective image on social using AddToAny plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, share, addtoany

I am using [addtoany](https://www.addtoany.com/) plugin on my website.
I am getting one issue, I have a list of images on my page and each list has share buttons.
Now when I click on any of the share buttons then I am getting only the first image on the social site.

For example, If I click on the second list share button then according to I have to get `1000*600` but I am getting `600*400` images.

```css
img {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="elements odd">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
  <!-- AddToAny BEGIN -->
  <div class="a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_default_style sharebtns" style="display:inline-block; text-align:center;">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="a2a_button_facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
      <li><a class="a2a_button_twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
      <li><a class="a2a_button_linkedin"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
      <li><a class="a2a_button_whatsapp"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a></li>
      <li><a class="a2a_button_email"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script async src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>
  <!-- AddToAny END -->
</div>
<div class="elements even">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x600/000/fff">
  <!-- AddToAny BEGIN -->
  <div class="a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_default_style sharebtns" style="display:inline-block; text-align:center;">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="a2a_button_facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
      <li><a class="a2a_button_twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
      <li><a class="a2a_button_linkedin"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
      <li><a class="a2a_button_whatsapp"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a></li>
      <li><a class="a2a_button_email"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script async src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>
  <!-- AddToAny END -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

update:

to use it with custom url add attibute `data-a2a-url` and `data-a2a-title` to the container

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />

<div class="elements odd">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
  <!-- AddToAny BEGIN -->
  <div class="a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_default_style sharebtns" 
       style="display:inline-block; text-align:center;"
       data-a2a-url="http://www.example.com/page1.html" 
       data-a2a-title="Example Page Title">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="a2a_button_facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
      <li><a class="a2a_button_twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
      <li><a class="a2a_button_linkedin"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
      <li><a class="a2a_button_whatsapp"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a></li>
      <li><a class="a2a_button_email"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <!-- AddToAny END -->
</div>
<div class="elements even">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x600/000/fff">
  <!-- AddToAny BEGIN -->
  <div class="a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_default_style sharebtns" 
       style="display:inline-block; text-align:center;" 
       data-a2a-url="http://www.example.com/page2.html" 
       data-a2a-title="Example Page Title">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="a2a_button_facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
      <li><a class="a2a_button_twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
      <li><a class="a2a_button_linkedin"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
      <li><a class="a2a_button_whatsapp"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a></li>
      <li><a class="a2a_button_email"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- AddToAny END -->
</div>

<script async src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>
```

---

your code is for sharing `current` page url, for image see below or read the [docs](https://www.addtoany.com/buttons/customize/image_sharing) for more

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x600/000/fff">
</div>

<script async src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>
<script>
  var a2a_config = a2a_config || {};
  a2a_config.overlays = a2a_config.overlays || [];
  a2a_config.overlays.push({});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, it's sharing the page URL. I have to share only specific posts.

Comment: answer edited, you need to add attribute `data-a2a-url`

Comment: Give me sometime to check your answer